# Conflict with script and prototype.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflicting-libraries

I have the following code and it looks like my first script is conflicting with prototype.js. Whenever I remove prototype.js the functionality of the first script works fine. When added back in, the functionality of prototype on the form is back, but my first script fails to work at all. How can I make this work?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);    
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
        $(id).fadeIn(2000);
        $("#textbox").focus();
    });

    $("#textbox").blur(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    }).keyup(function (e) {
        if($(this).val().substr($(this).val().length-1)=="?") {
            $('#mask').hide();
            $('.window').hide();
            setFromCCS($("#textbox").val());
        }
    });    
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
        setFromCCS($("#textbox").val());
    });        

    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });            

}); 

    function setFromCCS(ccs) {

        var index1 = ccs.indexOf("%B") + 2;
        var index2 = ccs.indexOf("^") + 1;
        var index3 = ccs.indexOf("^", index2 + 1) + 1;

        var cardNumber = ccs.substring( index1, index2 - 1);
        var expMonth = ccs.substr(index3 +2, 2);
        var expYear = ccs.substr(index3, 2);
        var holderName = ccs.substring(index2, index3 - 1);

var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var d = new Date(expMonth+"-01-20"+expYear);

        $("#input_6_cc_number").val(cardNumber);
        $("#input_6_cc_exp_month").val(monthNames[d.getMonth()]);
        $("#input_6_cc_exp_year").val("20"+expYear);
    }
</script> 


<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="https://cdn.jotfor.ms/js/vendor/flashcanvas.js?3.3.17929" type="text/javascript"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="https://cdn.jotfor.ms/js/vendor/jquery-1.8.0.min.js?v=3.3.17929" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jotfor.ms/js/vendor/jSignature.min.noconflict.js?3.3.17929" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jotfor.ms/js/vendor/jotform.signaturepad.js?3.3.17929" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="https://cdn.jotfor.ms/static/jotform.forms.js?3.3.17929" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jotfor.ms/static/prototype.forms.js"></script>
```

Jquery versions 1.4.4 1.2.6 and 1.8.0 are being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, change all $ in your script to jQuery, so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
```

becomes:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
    jQuery('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('href');
```

and so on.

And put:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

directly below your reference to the jQuery script file in `<head>`

Comment: I think jQuery also needs to be running in 'no conflict' mode - I've added this to the answer. Also see https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: Works! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you give "$" as parameter, you can use "$" instead of jQuery.

`jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('href');`

Answer (score 0):

It's only a `Scope` problem.

Move your function `setFromCCS` in the `$(document).ready(function() {` context!

Sample:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Other Code

    function setFromCCS(ccs) {
       // Code...
    }
});
```

Additional, create a new scope with anonymous function and add the jQuery context like this:

```
(function($) { // The jQuery-Context is "$"
     // Your Code

     function setFromCCS(ccs) {
       // Code...
    }
}(jQuery)); // Add jQuery-Context
```